# How to auto start services PHP Websocket on Ubuntu 14.0 when OS startup?

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, phpwebsocket

Below command is to start socket service.

```
nohup php -q server.php > my.log 2>&1 & echo $! > save_pid.txt
```

But the problem is when the OS shutdown and restart service socket will be stopped.

In this case, i want socket service auto start when the OS startup.

How should i do?